# I want to display images that are send to a specific folder in a sort of slideshow

Tags: python-3.x, photo

I have a piece of code right now that when i start it up it creates a black canvas and displays a image on it (With Tkinter) that i randomly grab from a folder i have selected with photos in it.

But right now i have to press esc to go to the next image. I would like it to be on a timer.

It also won't go to the next image.  [It says pyimage2 does not exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkJsd.png)

It would be great if someone can help me. I am incredibly new to python and don't know that much.

```js
from PIL import Image
import os, random
import time
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] == 2: 
    import Tkinter
    tkinter = Tkinter 
else:
    import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
i = True


def showPIL(pilImage):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    root.focus_set()
    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: (e.widget.withdraw(), e.widget.quit()))
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.configure(background='black')
    imgWidth, imgHeight = pilImage.size
    if imgWidth > w or imgHeight > h:
        ratio = min(w/imgWidth, h/imgHeight)
        imgWidth = int(imgWidth*ratio)
        imgHeight = int(imgHeight*ratio)
        pilImage = pilImage.resize((imgWidth,imgHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=image)
    root.mainloop()


while i == True:
    timer = 0
    while timer < 5:
        path = "C:/Users/thymen.hummel/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/Images"
        random_filename = random.choice([x
        for x in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
        ])
        pilImage = Image.open(f'C:/Users/thymen.hummel/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld/Images/{random_filename}')
        showPIL(pilImage)
        print(random_filename)
        timer += 1
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it by timer, you can do it using pygame.time.wait(). It takes input in milliseconds. see https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-speech-to-text-and-text-to-speech/. Instead of typing, you can name the name of the image and the program will open it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was actualy looking for more of a timer cause i want it to keep sliding through images even when i walk away.